# Java validation API: skip some rules without changing bean definition

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have an object in API jar, that I cannot change:

```
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String password;
}
```

In my code I need to use this object and to validate data inside, but, for example, I would like to let the password be empty. I cannot remove @NotNull from the class (and I cannot define groups for given constraint). How can I influence the validation without redefinig it from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to override the constraint definition of the specific class using either the constraint-mapping xml file or the Hibernate Validator specific API.

As described in the documentation, you can overide specific annotations (like the password field annotation) and leave the others untouched.

```
<constraint-mappings ...>

  <bean class="User" ignore-annotations="false">
    <field name="password" ignore-annotations="true">
        ... new annotations
    </field>
  </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```

further reading:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-xml-configuration.html#section-mapping-xml-constraints

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-specifics.html#section-programmatic-api

Comment: Thanks matthias, it looks like it could be it